# Adding the string of two list and store it in a new list

Tags: python, list

```
listA = ["A","B","C"]
listB = ["a","b","c"]
```

It's okay to write

```
listC = [listA[0]+listB[0], listA[1]+listB[1],listA[2]+listB[2]]
```

But when I write

```
i=0
listD = []
while i < len(listA):
        listD[i] = listA[i]+listB[i]
        i+=1
```

or

```
i=0
listD = []
while i < len(listA):
        listD[i] = str(listA[i])+str(listB[i])
        i+=1
```

It's not okay. 
PLease tell me why and how to correct it. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `zip` as @Rakesh suggested, but let me explain why your code does not work.

It would work if you did the following:

```
i=0
listD = []
while i < len(listA):
        listD.append(listA[i]+listB[i])
        i+=1
```

You cannot assign to `list[x]` to create a new item in the list. That is the syntax for modifying existing items. To add new items, use `append`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `zip` with list comprehension.

**Ex:**

```
listA = ["A","B","C"]
listB = ["a","b","c"]

print([i+v for i,v in zip(listA, listB)])
```

**Output:**

```
['Aa', 'Bb', 'Cc']
```

Comment: Thx for your help, but May I know what's wrong with my code? :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a loop you could use something like this.

```
listA = ["A","B","C"]
listB = ["a","b","c"]
[x+y for x,y in zip(listA,listB)]
# zip will output something like this [('A','a'),('B','b'),('C','c')]
```

Comment: Thx, helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to assign a value on the **index** which **does not** exist.

Python does not allow this.
Instead you can try this.

```
i=0
listD = []
while i < len(listA):
    listD.append(listA[i]+listB[i])
    i+=1
```

Comment for any doubt.

Comment: Thx!:) that helps

Answer (score 0):

> HII,
>     what mistake you are doing is,listD is an empty list but you are accessing with index,So its not possible to assign a value by index for an empty list

Try this,

```
listA = ["A","B","C"]
listB = ["a","b","c"]
print map(lambda x,y:x+y,listA,listB)

Result:['Aa', 'Bb', 'Cc']
```